# Grab all Custom Posts by multiple taxonomies and terms

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, terms, multi-taxonomy-query

I have 4 custom taxonomies with multiple terms for a "Members" page. I have a taxonomy of "location" and "organize" that I'm trying to separate into a list. I need to grab all posts by the "aba-therapists" term in the "organize" taxonomy and separate those by their "locations." If that makes sense to anyone. Something like this:

### ABA Therapist Term of Organize Taxonomy

#### Term 1 of Location Taxonomy

Post Post Post Post

#### Term 2 of Location Taxonomy

Post Post Post Post

#### Term 3 of Location Taxonomy

Post Post Post Post

This is the code I have, which just pulls in every post within the "members" CPT and organizes by every term:

```
    foreach ($taxonomies as $taxonomy){
        $terms = get_terms($taxonomy, array('orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'ASC'));

        if ( !empty( $terms ) && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                $args = array(
                    'post_type'           => $post_type,
                    'orderby'             => 'date',
                    'order'               => 'ASC',
                    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
                    'post_status'         => 'publish',
                    'posts_per_page'      => - 1,
                    'tax_query'           => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy'    => $taxonomy,
                            'field'       => 'slug',
                            'terms'       => $term->slug
                        )
                    )
                );
                $my_query = null;
                $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
                if ($my_query->have_posts()) {
                    echo '<div class="members"><div class="wrap"><h3>' . $term->name . '</h3></div><div class="details"><div class="wrap">';

                        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
                                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('cac-small'); ?>
                                <?php else : ?>
                                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/profile-placeholder.png" alt="Default Image">
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
                                </div>
                            </a>

                        <?php
                        endwhile; 
                } // END if have_posts loop
                    echo '</div></div></div>'; // Close 'details', 'wrap', & 'members' DIVs
                wp_reset_query(); 
            } // END foreach $terms
        }
    }
?>
```

I'm lost on where to start. Anyone have any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$terms = get_terms('location', array('orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'ASC'));

foreach( $terms as $term ) {
    $args = array(
        'post_type'           => $post_type,
        'orderby'             => 'date',
        'order'               => 'ASC',
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
        'post_status'         => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page'      => - 1,
        'tax_query'           => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy'    => 'organize',
                'field'       => 'slug',
                'terms'       => array( 'aba-therapist' )
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy'    => 'location',
                'field'       => 'slug',
                'terms'       => array( $term->slug )
            )
        )
    );

    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($my_query->have_posts()) {
        echo '<div class="members"><div class="wrap"><h3>' . $term->name . '</h3></div><div class="details"><div class="wrap">';

            while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('cac-small'); ?>
                    <?php else : ?>
                        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/profile-placeholder.png" alt="Default Image">
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <div class="caption">
                        <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
                    </div>
                </a>

            <?php
            endwhile; 
    } // END if have_posts loop
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Hope this code fill work for you. add ABA therapist header above.

Comment: I see what you did and thanks. Gives me a better understanding here. But, it's not pulling any the posts. Any idea?

Comment: check if the term slug and taxonomy names are correct.

Comment: Wow! Just missing an "s" on a term. Thank you!!